# Count Dates for each variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, unique

Need to sum the number of days a particular variable (animal) occurs

Also, need to sum the total hours.

In this example, I know macropod occurs on 11 days (all) and pig on (1). Need to replicate over 38 sites.

Appreciate help

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: based on what rule would you sum the hours?

Comment: @JvdV answered the question on days per species. I was wondering if I can use the same formula substituting HOURS for DAY, to get the total hours a species is present per site?

Comment: @OverflowStacker, I was thinking total hours per species. For species other than macropod that will dominate, it will give a nice insight into length of time to compare with number of days. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on a fraction of your data:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$18=D2,MATCH(DAY($A$2:$A$18),DAY($A$2:$A$18),0)),ROW($A$2:$A$18)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

And drag down

If you want an adaptive range within your formula you could use `INDEX()` within the formula to get to the last row:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=D2,MATCH(DAY($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),DAY($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),0)),ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

If you wish to extend this logic but with a certain site in mind, you could start working with boolean logic. In my case:

[image]

The formula in `G2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=F2)*($C$2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))=E2),MATCH(DAY($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),DAY($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))),0)),ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))-ROW($A$2)+1)>0))
```

Again, enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Pig",C2:C414)),(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(G2:G414,G2:G414))),"FAIL")

Comment: Sorry - failed attempt to reply. You Completely nailed it!! Above is what I was trying, would never of ended up with what you wrote. Thank you so much. Not be ungrateful, can I switch the MATCH (DAY - to - MATCH(HOUR to get the time each species is present?